Area denial organism for pre-industrial human beings on Earth
It has occurred to me that the human species has had it lucky.  Homo Sapiens evolved in Africa, and spread to most of the world with relatively primitive technology.  The last land settled by humans was New Zealand, settled by polynesians around 750 years ago.
There are places that humans can't go, of course.  Antarctica is too cold and too far from anywhere, and humans can't survive long-term in the sea.  However, I can't help thinking that we've had a lot of luck that there haven't been animals, plants or micro-organisms that could have denied us access to an entire continent that was otherwise hospitable.
So, my question is, What sort of biological threat (if any) could have prevented humans from successfully colonising an entire continent before the start of the industrial era?
The threat would have to be endemic to the target continent (and not forming an obstacle to reaching the place), and not able to migrate to wherever humans may already be established.  In effect, I'm asking answerers to design an organism that would keep humans from successfully colonising a continent.  The closer this organism is to a real organism that is or was present upon a real continent, the better, and obviously the more well-described and plausible the organism, the better.  I'd also prefer it if this organism was not a non-human tool-using species.  As a bonus, the longer the threat could deny humans access to the chosen continent after the start of the industrial revolution, the better.
For the sake of the question, let's suppose that the 'denied' continent is either the Americas or Australia, given that those continents are fairly isolated from Eurasia/Africa from where humans originated.    Let's say that the Industrial Era began circa 1750 AD.

You make things difficult asking for a whole continent, which implies an array of different climates and ecosystems.

You’re describing pre-industrial Africa. No need to invent anything, we were literally “not that lucky” in real life.

@scrwtp The issue being that Sub-Saharan Africans have some resistance to malaria, so even the really bad parts of Africa weren't entirely without human settlement.

Gorse is already pretty close to this.  The plant itself is like a combination of wild blackberries, thistle, and hawthorn.  If the climate is right (cool and damp) it will spread like those weeds, growing on even the thinnest coating of soil over rock, and will choke out other plants.  Destroying gorse is a major undertaking and it will grow back from any fragment of missed root, but it is possible with primitive tools (axes, mattocks, and fire).
To make it truly deterrent, you need to add one thing: urushiol.  This is the oil in poison ivy that makes 97% of humans allergic to contact with the plant.  If gorse produced urushiol, even if it only grew in the littoral zone of a continent, it would make the place proof against human colonization until at least 19th century technology is developed.
Attempts to hack out "poison gorse" would be disabling to nearly everyone involved, and burning it would be worse, as the smoke carries the urushiol and inhaling it can be fatal (especially without 20th century or later medical technology).
Of course, there are other plants more toxic than poison ivy -- including some that will induce pain so intense that people have killed themselves to escape it after unknowingly using the leaves for intimate contact applications.  Provide any hardy weed-like plant species (ideally ones with thorns like blackberry, gorse, etc.) with poisons like that and it will become an interdiction agent even for animals that naturally eat both gorse and poison ivy -- only animals specifically adapted to them can live in them or feed from them.

Even in modern times, we still have trouble dealing with tumbleweed.  As for plant chemicals, plenty of plants have gone far worse than urushiol (e.g., the Machineel tree).
The idea of a plant-based area denial is very convincing.

Guess where Pharaoh sends prisoners now?

Goats are stone age tools that eat gorse and poison ivy. On top of being available to humans as poison gorse mitigation tools, I think they (or something with similar ability to eat the poison gorse) would take over over the wild animal population of anywhere poison gorse was taking over the plant population, probably as it was happening in the first place, naturally mitigating the takeover.

Another very real plant area denial is giant hogweed (Heracleum mantegazzianum) which has quite recently required coordinated efforts to remove from pretty large areas in my country.

The horizontal scrub of Tasmania comes pretty close — forests dominated by a specific species which forms an almost impenetrable thicket, and which is very difficult to clear.  Areas of horizontal scrub were essentially uninhabited before European colonisation, and were only very, very slowly cleared for settlement thereafter.  That said, this works (like gorse) by being one specific ecosystem — it can’t rule out a whole otherwise-normal-looking continent.

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine If the poison gorse or "thorny hogweed" or perhaps a toxic version of horizontal scrub etc. had the climate tolerance of hemp, it could...

@gs what if it is invasive?

Over hundreds/thousands of years, the humans in the area would also evolve to not be allergic to urushiol. Some people already aren't allergic, so it's just a matter of selecting for those genes.

@ChristopherKing worst case scenario, the follow-on wave of invasive species (e.g. goats) live in a competition-free predator-free poisongorse paradise when they get there. See e.g. rabbits and cats in Australia.  Ecological devastation follows, which is good for the settlers, because the ecology sucked for us and we'd rather get rid of it

@causative That won't work, however, for genuinely toxic plants like giant hogweed or machineel.

Other Hominid
Earth has a species that is extremely good at eliminating apex predators and other potential competition.
Humanity.
We've removed a number of very capable species from entire continents - from all of the Ice Age Megafauna to lions, and brown bears, and wolves. To the extent that these creatures exist in Europe and North America, it's because the locals have made an active effort to rescue them from the extinction that we initiated.
Humans are really good at removing "unwanted" competition.
So build a human analog.
Think carnivorous, pack hunting chimps or extremely aggressive flavor of gorilla.
Or perhaps look closer to home. The last common ancestor between chimps and humans is ~10 million years ago, and anatomically modern humans arose ~2 million years ago. So pick a hominid that existed between those times, and have them find the forbidden continent first.
Probably better to keep these hominid more animal-like than human-like for your purposes - it's not a forbidden continent if you can talk to the locals and work something out; they've got to kill and eat you before you have a chance to barter for your life.

I'd also prefer it if this organism was not a non-human tool-using species.  This is getting awfully close to that line.

If I wanted something smart, I'd populate the place with territorial fast-breeding smart monkeys with blowpipes, flint knives and curare...

This is a Frame Challenge

From the moment the invaders arrived, breathed our air, ate and drank, they were doomed. They were undone, destroyed, after all of man's weapons and devices had failed, by the tiniest creatures that God in his wisdom put upon this earth. By the toll of a billion deaths, man had earned his immunity, his right to survive among this planet's infinite organisms. And that right is ours against all challenges. For neither do men live nor die in vain. (War of the Worlds (2005))

The truth is that humanity is incredibly adept at overcoming problems. That's the entire point of evolution and becoming the pinnacle of that evolution: the remarkable engine of our existence has become one that both consciously and unconsciously fights off attackers and can dynamically adapt (at a cost...) to pretty much anything that's thrown at us.
Therefore, asking "what biological threat" is the wrong question. It doesn't matter if you pick a plant, or an animal, or a disease, or a roving band of aliens, or anything else. That's just the MacGuffin that lets you get on with your story. There's literally only one variable that can rationalize late colonization of a continent.
Time...
The earlier humanity steps foot on the continent the longer it has to learn to overcome whatever you've put in its path, which it will eventually do. Armor plated rhinoceros? Run it off a cliff. Particularly nasty disease? Isolation, change of diet, and time. A dangerous plant that could keep humanity from settling in? How'd life evolve there in the first place? We can analyze like this with everything. Humanity has already done this with everything. There isn't a biological-what that will stop colonization.
Your only choice is to find a reason to delay stepping foot on the continent in the first place. A method that requires industrialization to overcome.
How do we do that?

Using Zealandia as a basic reference, let's assume your world is entering a cooling period, so the ocean is receding fast — exposing a continent very late in your world's development. Technology required: dikes on a continental scale, engine-driven pumps, earth moving.

Using Australia as an example, let's make the continent a little smaller and push it a little further toward the pole. This would make the continent a lot harder to get to. However, the Age of Sail was able to overcome just about every ocean-borne obstacle in a very short period of time. Nevertheless, technology required: storm stabilization, off-shore ports/platforms, heating.


You know, part of the problem is that humanity has this insatiable curiosity — an absolute ache to know everything. People were traversing the oceans long before the Age of Sail, just not efficiently. Thus, your desire to deny access until after industrialization strains credulity. And offends the Vikings. I'm just sayin'...

The continent, for reasons I can't explain, is 100% surrounded by sheer cliffs, which would make landing anywhere disastrous. Make it basalt or some really hard rock that rationalizes glorious waterfalls from amazing heights that haven't worn down into traditional deltas. Technology required: elevating machinery, off-shore ports/platforms, steel cables.

Whatever the solution, it can't be biological as humanity has already proven its ability to overcome every biological problem: the blessing of being a problem-solving species with a great immune system (well done Mother Nature!). Your solution must be one that delays access to the continent in the first place. Of course, that does suggest one somewhat implausible biological-what...

A very large, particularly aggressive and fairly ubiquitous sea monster that keeps shipping to the shores until the invention of ironclads. Or perhaps something small, somewhat barnaclish that can chew through timber in a week, making open sea sailing... problematic.

And the reason that works is that there's no practical way to keep a region clear once cleared of the infesting whatever-it-is. The problem is so large that it can't be solved without a minimum of technology (steel hulls). Example of the problem: outer space.
Like I say, a MacGuffin to delay colonization.

Of course we're going to be able to overcome pretty much any problem we encounter on our home planet... eventually.  That was the point of the before the start of the industrial era part of the question.

@MontyWild But you asked for something that would delay until industrialization. We need only look at evolution to know that the only way to guarantee that would be a technological dependency.

let's make the continent a little smaller and push it a little further toward the pole — you mean like New Zealand?

That quote in the beginning... Given what happens IRL whenever a slightly new, highly infectious disease appears, imagine what happens when you encounter a planet worth of new diseases all at once, that are somehow able to infect you and spread, and that no one in your population has any kind of immunity to.

@kutschkem That isn't hard to imagine at all, per my link viz-a-viz isolation, diet and time (c.f. when the Europeans first visited South America). The problem is that we don't have a new planet filled with alien diseases. We have the same planet all those disease and the people evolved on. Hence my frame challenge.

@gerrit New Zealand isn't a continent... but that's the idea, although probably something more like half the distance to the ice shelf.

@JBH If it's even smaller, at some point it ceases to be a continent.

"The truth is that humanity is incredibly adept at overcoming problems."  Yes "That's the entire point of evolution and becoming the pinnacle of that evolution:"  No.  There is no "point" of evolution, and certainly no drive toward any one species becoming it's 'pinnacle'.  The average mammalian species lasts about a million years from speciation to extinction; no one 'wins' evolution.

The current dominance of humans has very little to do with evolution and almost everything to do with cultural transmission.  Our species at its 'pinnacle', for the same reasons we are good at problem-solving, are currently making it entirely possible to disrupt this cultural transmission with nuclear war or a climate disaster.

@Kirt I believe you lost the intent of my response in the depths of your ideology. Don't worry too much about it, humanity has  been successfully finding ways to avert doom for a long time and if we're fortunate to make that million-year mark you mention, the magic of our technology will be breathtaking - both the power to save and the power to destroy, as all tools are.

Re: 'The intent of your response', I think your answer is fine, and I agree with its argument: Whatever natural barriers there are to exploration / colonization, humans are indeed clever and inventive and they will surely overcome those barriers if properly motivated. I don't have a problem with your answer; I just think you fundamentally misunderstand how evolution works, if you think that there is some sort of pre-ordained purpose to make and preserve humans as dominant. To the extent that I have an "ideology" it is that of our current, mainstream understanding of evolutionary biology.

A disease would do the trick. Humans show up, and they die. They'd soon avoid showing up. Especially somewhere remote like Australia with no known resources worth having.
Perhaps something like lethal dengue fever which kills people even today sometimes. A mosquito bites them and they're history while learning a whole new World of pain on the way out. The disease might be prevalent in marsupials and non lethal to them, but deadly to humans.

The problem with a disease is that it could be brought back to the home continent, which violates a condition of the question.

No need to take it back. It kills humans, they don't make it back. Can't survive in dead bodies and mosquiros don't bite corpses

At least some virii do in fact remain viable in dead bodies or on surfaces.  I don't know specifically about dengue, but "smallpox blankets" were a real thing in the 19th century and possibly the 18th, even though people then didn't know what actually caused smallpox.  They just knew it would kill 70-80% of a population that had never encountered it before...

It would need to be a disease with a 100% death rate in humans, a very short incubation time, and no possibility for asymptomatic carriers or individuals with natural immunity. No such disease has ever existed. It’s more akin to a manufactured bioweapon than a naturally occurring disease.

Still, a regular disease could be a mostly valid answer to the question. Some colonists arrive, catch a disease that kills most of them, then the survivors flee home and bring the disease with them. The resulting pandemic devastates the home continent, causing them to place a total ban on exploring the new continent. The ban is not lifted until a better understanding of virology and disease control is developed in the industrial age.

@chai_tea That wont really work well since after the pandemic a good chunk of the survivors will be immune or at least resistant to the desease.

@LazyLizard Yes, they’ll technically be immune but they might not understand that concept in a pre-industrial society. The fear of causing another pandemic might keep them from trying to explore the new continent again even if the threat is long gone. It’s more of a “they won’t go” solution than a “they can’t go” one. I admit it’s not a perfect solution since it only takes one brave/reckless expedition to prove it’s safe again. But if making such an expedition is illegal then it might not occur for a long time.

@ZeissIkon "smallpox blankets" were a real thing in the 19th century Source?

@user76284 Major element of US history. Google it. It doesn't need sources any more than the existence of WW2.

@Graham Should be easy for you to post a source, then.

@ZeissIkon, not 19th century, 18th century, and it was fairly ineffective: the primary transmission route of smallpox is aerosols.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Fort_Pitt#Biological_warfare

@Graham : it does need sources, as it is considered even by some serious historians as either a myth or an overblown generalization of a single instance of a single person. It's not true that it's as obvious as the very existence of WW2. https://quod.lib.umich.edu/p/plag/5240451.0001.009/--did-the-us-army-distribute-smallpox-blankets-to-indians?rgn=main;view=fulltext

@chai_tea Can I introduce you to anthrax? Even today, it isn't something we can effectively fight, and if you survive? Reinfection is very possible. 90-100% fatality rate when inhaled. Deadly in a few days, so no travelling back before that. And it can last VERY LONG in frozen animal corpses. Imagine arriving to an island littered in frozen corpses carrying the disease.

Biggest problem is how does this disease exist?  diseases don't evolve in a vacume, they evolve to attack the hosts that are present.  A disease this lethal to humans is unlikely to evolve if humans are no where around.  You're best excuse is zoonosis from another species but unless that species is so human like that they might as well be humans zoonosis is dependent on a random mutation happening while human hosts are present to exploit.  You won't get zoonosis happening with ever visit.  There is no logical reason a disease so perfectly evolved to attack humans appears out of nowhere

Lack of Iodine
Iodine deficiency is a chronic problem for many inland areas, but some areas have a more severe deficiency than others.  There are regions in North America that tribes would pass through but not settle in.  Not until there were ways to import seafood was it feasible.
This region is much more deficient.
The shores might feature settlements, in that case.  Perhaps they are too vulnerable to flukes without the hinterland to back them up.

This is an interesting one. The question made me think of early Viking settlers that died out in places where food wasn't plentiful enough. The question does want an "organism" specifically, so just having too little iodine in the water isn't enough; it needs to be caused by something living.

Answer is good on most points, but question did ask for the barrier to stand as long as possible after industrial revolution. 1757 is when limes were discovered to help sailors with vitamin C. That suggests that similar deficiencies wouldn't last much past the industrial revolution.

@JollyJoker A lack of iodine is arguably caused by the wrong living things. The organisms are the ecology that keep migratory species that would bring iodine into the area from settling or passing through -- just as they deny humans from settling.

Incompatible essential amino acids
As far as we can tell, there was only one (successful) origin of life on Earth, and every living thing is related.  That means that most of our biochemistry is compatible - you can eat pretty much anything and break it down into the kind of chemical building blocks your body needs.
But suppose you had a planet with two independent origins of life that then developed two incompatible biochemistries - for example, L and D chirality on amino acids.  Any given species from L-origin would be nutrient-deficient if its only source of protein was D-origin plants and animals.
These two origins would have to have been separated for long enough for a robust and diverse flora and fauna to have evolved.  On Earth, life likely began in the ocean, so we need a world with two oceanic basins completely separated by land from one another.  In each basin, first unicellular and then multicellular life arose, each with its own biochemistry.
By the time multicellular life was moving onto land, the life emerging from each ocean was fundamentally incompatible with one another.  If the strip of land separating the two oceans was narrow enough, it would likely develop a mixed flora and fauna of both L and D types, but the land on the "far side" of the oceans would be filled with species of almost entirely one type.
If humans originated from apes in the L region of the world, they could, with pre-industrial technology, cross the land separating the oceans and explore the far shores of the D region.  But the farther they pushed into the D region, the less nutritious the endemic food would be.  With pre-industrial knowledge of chemistry (amino acids were first described chemically in the 1930's), humans would likely not understand that everything that seemed perfectly edible - grains, nuts, fruits, game animals, all providing usable calories - was ultimately lacking in essential amino acids for them and that they were becoming malnourished.  They could survive as explorers, bringing their own food with them, and they could even attempt colonies, planting the crops and bringing the domesticated animals from home.  But their animals would become malnourished as well, any human children and domestic animal young would quickly exhibit metabolic diseases, and unless they were able to tend enough crops to produce all of their own dietary needs, without supplementing it from local food, while at the same time realizing the necessity to do so, ultimately their colonies would be doomed to fail.
Both exploration itself and supplying colonies would be made more difficult by the land barrier between the oceans.  Even in the age of sail, it was preferable to sail around the tip of South America than to land in central America, cross the jungle on foot, and construct new ships on the shore of the other ocean.  Similarly with Africa and the narrow distance by land between the Red Sea and the Mediterranean.  The impetus for building the Suez Canal and Panama Canal was to make these journeys possible for ocean-going ships.  In a world of completely separate oceans, where "sailing around" is not a possibility, you would need to establish a port with a ship-building capability on the nearest shore of the other ocean before extensive exploration and colonization was possible, and any such port would be largely dependent on local foods.  If the land you had to cross was wider than the isthmus of Panama, that would pose considerable logistical difficulties.

This is about as far as you can get from being like existing organisms... and if it was actually a thing, organisms would have evolved the ability to metabolise opposite chirality molecules millions of years ago.

@MontyWild It's your question, of course, so perhaps I am not understanding the terms.  Even though no existing organisms have denied humans access to a continent, you are asking for an organism that could do that while still being as close as possible to existing organisms.  My proposition is organisms that are exactly like existing organisms except for an accident of history that has them using opposite chirality.

@MontyWild As for whether organisms would have evolved the ability to metabolize other chiralities, possibly prokaryotes.  Eukaryotes tend to have much more restrictive biochemistries and the 'cost' of such evolution likely outweighs the 'benefits'.  Evidence of this is the fact that there are essential amino acids to begin with - why aren't humans able to synthesize all of the amino acids we need?

@Kirt: Assuming convergent evolution, organisms may well be similar to existing organisms despite opposite chirality.  However, evolving two chiralities in the same biosphere is incredibly unlikely, so this approach is rather unconvincing unless dealing with separate biospheres (fine for aliens, questionable for life that evolved on the same planet).

@Brian I'm not a paleobiochemist, but I was working from the assumption that initial chirality is going to be a random event at the origin of life, but then will become self-reinforcing.  Thus we need two independent origins of life (which I state).  Then we need enough time for multicellular life to evolve from our two separate origins before they contact one another, since early contact would eliminate a chirality through competition.  The problem is how to effectively have two independent biospheres on the same planet - and that's what I thought my answer addressed.  No?

I really love this idea, but I have to agree with other commenters that it doesn't work very well. The two landmasses would not stay ecologically separated. For one thing, seeds would drift from one to the other, and colonizing plants of the opposite chirality would in fact have an amazing competitive advantage early on, since local animals couldn't eat them. Over time, both biochemistries would exist in parallel on both landmasses. This in turn would mean considerable selective pressure on heterotrophic organisms (including people) to be able to digest both.

@Olle Once multicellular life left the two isolated oceans, yes there would be a mixing of chiralities.  A high mountain range between the two ocean basins would prevent a lot of mixing, but if there were flying animals eventually seeds would cross.  And yet even on earth limited distributions is a thing, and invasive species are nearly always associated with post-industrial human-mediated spread.  Arguing that 'mixing must occur' ignores the real science of biogeography, Wallace's Line, cacti not making it to Australia until 1788 etc. etc.

@Olle "plants of the opposite chirality would in fact have an amazing competitive advantage early on, since local animals couldn't eat them. "  No.  Local animals could and would eat them - they just wouldn't be nourished by them.  So unless the local animals have some amazing biochemical sense to detect that they are not being nourished by the opposite chirality plants, they would have no reason not to eat them.

@Olle "[There would be]considerable selective pressure on heterotrophic organisms (including people) to be able to digest both." No. Selective pressure can't force a species through an adaptive valley just because the neighboring peak is higher. Selection works through the difference between this generation and the next, and the cost of developing and maintaining redundant biochemical pathways would likely be too high, if it was even possible for eukaryotes to do. As I mentioned before, if you only consider future benefits, humans should be able to create all amino acids.  Costs matter.

@Kirt To your first point: on geological timescales, species spreading across huge stretches of ocean has always been a thing. Consider isolated volcanic landmasses like Hawai'i, which have never shared a land bridge with anywhere, yet were colonized by many plant and animal lineages long before humans accelerated the process.
I think it is fair to say that mixing must occur. Biogeographic boundaries like Wallace's line do exist, but they

@ Kirt To your second point: that's true, local animals would eat the invaders at first. But there'd now be selective pressure on THEM to avoid eating these plants that give no nourishment. This would not require any sensory mechanism to sense the chirality difference itself. Animals already evolve to prefer foods that better need their nutritive needs.

@ Kirt To your third point: I only said that there would be selective pressure, not that there wouldn't be evolutionary constraints, which you're totally right about. But again, we're talking geological timescales, which increases the chances that some lineage would have developed the required biochemical pathways. There would have been the occasional opposite-chirality organisms drifting across the divide for the entire several billions of years that the two biospheres had been separated.

Basically what I'm saying is that, unless I'm looking at it wrong, this scenario requires a series of absolutes to be true — NO mixing, NO dietary or foraging adaptation to mirrored biochemistry, NO adaptation to digest mirrored biochemistry. Yes, biogeographic boundaries exist, but species do often cross them. Yes, maladaptive behaviors exist, but species often adapt out of them over time. Yes, fitness valleys exist, but they can sometimes be crossed given time and the right circumstances. I just don't there could be this kind of clean break for billions of years. But it's a cool idea.

@Olle On Earth, the first land plants appeared about 460 million years ago.  I'm not sure why your argument is based on a geologic timescale of billions of years.  And I don't understand why you think my idea requires absolutes: "NO mixing", "NO adaptation" etc.  All that is required is that humans and whichever domesticated animals they bring with them not have evolved metabolisms capable of processing opposite chirality plants and animals.

Parasites
The difficulty with (many) diseases is that they are very specific in their mode of attack, and co-evolve with the target population.  That is, it's a little implausible that a spectacularly lethal to humans, wildly contagious virus would exist in a place where humans have never existed.  (Never mind that such diseases tend to grow less lethal over time, because killing the host too quickly dries up the evolutionary swimming pool.)
However, more sophisticated organisms can be a bit more adaptable.  Sure, maybe there's a flesh-eating bacteria that the local fauna has adapted to, and humans would not have a resistance in to, something like that, but don't sell our immune systems short.  Next step up is a slightly more sophisticated organism like malaria (single-celled, but not a bacteria).
It's significant to note that, except for native Africans, who were somewhat more adapted, the inner continent of Africa was in fact largely unexplored until (and well into) "industrial times," because non-native settlers / explorers (and their non-native livestock) would eventually succumb to "tropical" diseases (malaria beingvthe big one).  (This resistance to exploration was why Africa was called "The Dark Continent".)  Parts of Central America were likewise resistant to settling, because of similar conditions.
However, this was all climate-based.  While the jungles were considered impenetrable, the coasts of Africa were explored (and settled) by foreigners.  It's quite plausible that regions of a continent could be uninhabitable by humans (other than those who had been there for a long time), but the whole thing?  That's a tougher sell.
Anyway, aggressive parasites, which also affect other organisms to a lesser extent, seems like your best bet.  Malaria, African Trypanosomiasis (sleeping sickness), filariasis (wait, that one's not lethal, it's just nightmare fuel), brain-eating amoeba...
Don't drink the water, don't go swimming, don't let the bugs bite you.


A poisonous variant of Kudzu
Kudzu is an extremely fast growing vine that probably originated from either Japan or China. It can grow about a foot a day and will grow over literally anything. Also, its practically impossible to get rid of. It has extremely deep root systems which can't be pulled out and if you damage the root system I believe the roots just split into separate plants. In the parts of the world it has spread to, people regularly have to just cut it down with mowers or goats - at regular intervals. Even if a fictional variant was only half as poisonous as poison ivy, early man wouldn't be able to settle in such an area as keeping village and farm areas clear of the poisonous Kudzu would be a full time occupation and any paths they cut through it to get around would disappear in days. Its a fun example as it would be area denial by a plant that is closer to irritating then deadly. You could literally have a situation where the humans have gone to "war" with poisonous kudzu on a fairly narrow land bridge as humans were pushed off one continent by the spread of the irritating weed and the humans understand that if it gets passed the land bridge it will swamp the new continent as well.


Rampant bulldog ants
There are several species of ants which are hazardous to live near, as once you annoy them, they will keep attacking you - and will often follow you great distances to continue the assault. You can kill a wolf that is stalking you but killing ants doesn't really stop an ant attack. You are literally forced to flee until the ants stop chasing. Ants usually keep each other in check as hives will start attacking each other when they collide or will split into smaller, fighting hives if one hive gets too big. Change this behaviour slightly and you have a continent awash with ant hives all over the place. Humans can travel there but its not safe to sleep in those lands - and its hard to colonize a place when you can't lie down at night.

T-Rex with no fire aversion.
There is a reason that mammals didn't bother to evolve while there were large predators around. Include an intelligent predator which is larger then an elephant and most humans will takes their odds at just swimming into the ocean over playing with giants.



I wish you'd made this three separate answers. The ants are excellent and unique answer here. T-Rex fails: every continent where humans have shown up has seen its megafauna go extinct shortly thereafter. We're very good at hunting large predators... very good.

We very good at hunting megafauna which are herbivores. If there are any references to us co-existing with extra large predators, I've missed those videos and papers. Glad you enjoyed the ant idea, and getting comments on one's ideas is much more appreciated then up or down votes :p

The large predators appear to get hunted to extinction — we don’t coexist with them. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_Pleistocene_extinctions#:~:text=Major%20extinctions%20occurred%20in%20Australia,moderate%20extinctions%20than%20other%20regions. Notable: there are no replacements in their ecological niches… we don’t allow things that hunt us.

Pathogenic Microbes
Because anything human can seek and locate, human can exterminate.
So it must be invisible.
A airborn bacteria with a life cycle relying on geographically-specific combinations of animals and\or plants, innocuous to them but very fast in infecting and killing humans.
The plants\animals involved should otherwise be relatively common outside the Zone, but not all together, making it close to impossible to realize is the presence of that specific combination that kills the people.
Bonus point for one involved species looking extremely similar to another completely unrelated species to increase confusion.
Once you are in the Zone, it's basically granted you get infected and die before you can reach the "other" side.
Infected humans are infective agents as well, but they show symptoms very fast and the infecting range is very limited so people just stay X days away from the Zone which is enough to keep people from infecting populated centers... which also keeps them from developing antibodies by mass-infection.
The pathogen should have a short life-span unable to survive and reproduce outsie the Zone, as well as making easy to contain the occasional infection before it becomes an epidemic. Which in turn makes extremely unlikely for natural resistance to occurr.

Shipworms - eg. Teredo Navalis
Why attack the humans when you can just eat their boats?
The Worms
According to Wikipedia on these little guys:

Teredo navalis is a very destructive pest of submerged timber. In the Baltic Sea, pine trees can become riddled with tunnels within 16 weeks of being in the water and oaks within 32 weeks, with whole trees 30 cm (12 in) in diameter being completely destroyed within a year. Ships' timbers are attacked, wrecks destroyed and sea defences damaged.

To suit the needs of your world, I suggest just making them breed a bit faster and have this continent be far away from the homeland. This combination gives the shipworms enough time to weaken the boat to the point that it sinks well before the intrepid explorers can make it back home.
The Expeditions
This leaves basically two options for each expedition.
Fast - they arrive, do some exploring, resupply, and leave. They don't notice the damage until it's too late. When they do notice the problem, they're almost entirely helpless to stop it. You can try to de-worm the ship, but most of them will be on the outside hull under the water line. The ship starts taking on water and eventually just sinks, if the weakened hull doesn't break apart in a storm first. Everyone dies quickly.
Slow - the arrive and take their time exploring more of the coast and maybe going up a few rivers. They do notice the damage either shortly before they leave or soon enough after that they can turn around. Many of the individual people survive the first week or two. Some people die off early, learning the hard way which berries are poisonous, which snakes and spiders are venomous, and which areas have large predators. On a timeline of years, any attempts to make another ship to sail home end up infested with worms and fail. On a timeline of decades they don't have the women to replace their population. If there are a few women in the group, they are also more likely to die in childbirth. Everyone dies eventually.
The History
In the ancient days, you get the classic /here be dragons/ on maps, because anyone who says they're going there never comes back. Even the more amazing navigational and logistical feats of Polynesian explorers would fall to these tiny worms.
In a more industrialized era, you start to get metal ships and people taking less stock in old folk tales. It was believed by Eratosthenes around 240 B.C. that the Earth is a sphere and he had a good estimate of its size. Eventually someone with a metal ship would try the long way around, and stumble on a pristine continent.

The threat would have to be endemic to the target continent (and not forming an obstacle to reaching the place)  This is an obstacle, not something endemic.

Lack of vitamin C
A treatment for Scurvy was historically demonstrated in 1747, matching your year of 1750 almost exactly. The area could lack berries or citrus fruits, perhaps just not in significant amounts due to birds or rodents eating them. Once the solution is understood, implementing it and therefore spreading across the new continent becomes easy. Historically it did take a few decades to become universally accepted.

Tse-tse flies and sleeping sickness
There's a precedent for this:
In sub-Saharan Africa, the tsetse fly (genus Glossina) is a vector for Trypanosoma parasites, which cause African trypanosomiasis (sleeping sickness) in humans and nagana in livestock. This parasitic disease severely affects cattle, making it impossible to establish large-scale herding or farming in infested regions. The fly thrives in humid and savannah environments, creating vast zones where agricultural and pastoral activities are limited. If such a vector had evolved on a different continent, its role as a biological barrier could plausibly have denied humans access to the ecological benefits of domesticated livestock, stalling settlement and development in those regions before industrial advances enabled control of the disease.
Note that humans did somewhat overcome this, they do live there, so it would not be a working barrier to the peopling of other lands. However, the population density in the affected areas is low and human development is pretty bad, forget about science.

In the US in the 19th century, Locusts were a major problem for settlers. They could swarm in their billions, eating everything in their path. They were largely defeated by accident: the locusts bred on marsh and mud on riverbanks, and were probably largely defeated by the river trade which drained the marshes and cut down trees close to rivers for fuel.

They were a major problem. They still did not prevent settlers, did not drive them to extinction, did not stop more and more settlers to arrive.

The original post suggested a date of 1750 rather than 1874. There would have been no railways and little river traffic to bring supplies. There would have been little state organisation or funds to come to the rescue. Most of the settlers would have perished.

Most answers focus on things that would harm human settlers directly, but I think there's an easier way to get this effect.  This continent is densely populated with a pest species roughly based on the Rasberry crazy ant.  They build large underground colonies with multiple queens and are extremely resilient (we really don't have any good way to deal with them in modern day, if you try to kill them they just reproduce faster).  They love to crawl into and swarm inside enclosed spaces, like appliances, wall cavities, or boxes.
The problem isn't that they attack the humans (their bite is relatively tame).  The ants cause a problem because they go after the humans' stored food reserves.  If you pick fresh crops and can cook and eat them fast enough then you'll be fine.  But if you try to store that food, you'll wake up tomorrow to find that the ants have already eaten most of it.  They're so small that they can get into the impossibly tight gap in a jar lid or the seam between planks in a crate.  They leave live plants alone, but anything that is harvested or that falls to the ground will start seeing ant damage within hours.
You have no practical way to store food for more than a day or two.  There's no way you can harvest and store enough food to survive through winter.  Any seeds you collect this year will be long gone before you can plant them next year.  If you try to put too much food in one place (like a cellar or silo), the ants will swarm it and start turning it into a new nest.  They've spent millenia building underground tunnels that cover pretty much the entire continent, so they can surprise you anywhere, at any time, and in overwhelming numbers.  The end result is a continent where you cannot stay long enough to explore in any meaningful way.  You'd have to subsist solely on foraging.  That might be possible in the fertile interior during certain months, but the coastal areas don't have much that's edible for humans so you won't survive long enough to make it that far.
An industrialized society would have some advantages because we have pest-proof food packing processes like vacuum sealing.  The ants would present new problems, though, because they can swarm inside machines to the point where they break something, sometimes even shorting out an electrical circuit and causing a fire.
The first time you're able to really explore this continent is after you have boats propelled by mechanized motors.  They will give you the power to navigate up the swift-flowing rivers and into the interior of the continent.  You can survive ant-free as long as you stay on the water.

Fungi
There are exist a lot of fungi with many different properties.
Some fungi are poisonous and some have spores which can be bad for your health when you get them into your lungs.
Some fungi can even work as a huge network among an entire forest and can become several kilometers/miles large.
If you do some fancy combinations, you could get a usually harmless fungus which covers huge portions of a continent, but with a season where it distributes its spores (e.g. in autumn).
The wildlife could have adopted to the spores, but the spores could be harmful for humans, especially in big amounts.
One bonus effect: The continent could be habitable most time of the year, but not for a permanent stay.

An ecosystem dependend on a mineral
There are two qustions to answer here. First why the organism(s) makes an area uninhabitable. Second why only this area is no-go.
So introduce a plant. Rapid growing like a weed. Destroying any human farm produce. Make it poisonous or at least non-edible. You may add animal species that feeds on the plant if you want, as long as those animals are a threat to humans (directly or as hosts for micro organisms) and/or not useful as a source of food or skin/fur/etc.
The reason this plant is contained to one continent is that it requires a specific mineral in the soil. This mineral could realistically be contained to an isolated geographical location. This way, even if explorers brought the plant-of-doom, it would not spread in the old world.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ragweed
It grows everywhere, and it protects local animals from human hunters- rewarding these for spreading it. Now- add a narcotics property, so that those tasked with "removing" it become addicted to the stuff- and some anti-touch contaminate similar to poison ivy. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poison_ivy
Touch it and you are addicted and rotting alive at the same time. Of course- when you have nature adapt to a smart organism (as it had time too in africa) you see all kinds of nasty things pop up - being propped up by the thinning out ecosystem.
The plant could spread a human version of cordyceps on destruction https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cordyceps or life in a symbiosis with lethal organsim- like the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarbagan_marmot who is a repository for the black death. Kill the plant, it alerts its friend, who then bites you infecting you with rabbies.

That could lead to a pretty cool sci-fi device -- the human population split into the "dirty" weed controllers (addicted lower class, own culture) and the "clean" farmers. They need each other, but obv., there's benefit for one group to dominate the other. Who's on top may even go back and forth over millenia...

Let those who are touched by foulness of nature be not welcome in your door or be stained by their shadows

A mirrored continent
No, I'm not resorting to fantasy (completely), I mean molecules in organisms that could, depending on whether or not it is in the right side of the mirror, either heal you or kill you.
Some background:
In some organic molecules, they have the property of chirality, aka "handedness". This means they can be "right-handed" or "left-handed", just like your left hand and right hand. They behave in the same manner in most physical properties but interact with other chiral molecules differently. Think of it as trying to put on a left-handed baseball glove with your right hand, it just doesn't fit.

Why does that matter?
Many, many organic molecules are chiral. In fact, a lot of your enzymes in your body is chiral, and can only process certain molecules in the correct handedness. If you're lucky, human body can ignore, have a different effect
from, or correct the wrong handedness. In other cases, enzymes will process the molecule in a way that can kill you or even your unborn child.
However, let's imagine a scenario where there's a separate continent from the main Eurasia since early Earth, Ailartsua. It is itself a completely different origin of life, and all organism living in or nearby has adopted the opposite chirality from Eurasia, to the point where common sucrose in Ailartsua was (2S,3S,4R,5R,6S)-2-{[(2R,3R,4R,5S)-3,4-Dihydroxy-2,5-bis(hydroxymethyl)oxolan-2-yl]oxy}-6-(hydroxymethyl)oxane-3,4,5-triol instead of (2R,3R,4S,5S,6R)-2-{[(2S,3S,4S,5R)-3,4-Dihydroxy-2,5-bis(hydroxymethyl)oxolan-2-yl]oxy}-6-(hydroxymethyl)oxane-3,4,5-triol. (That's the chemistry way of saying it's a complete mirror image of the "real" sucrose)
For the sake of this question, let's assume there evolved a complete ecosystem in Ailartsua based on all of these mirror plane molecules, and Ailartsua was really, really far away from Eurasia. Early explorers finding Ailartsua will (painfully) discover that although there's many exotic fruits, animals, and fish throughout Ailartsua, they may survive for a short period, but will somehow deteriorate in health over time (kidney, liver, and possibly pancreas fail, among other possible damages to human body). Worse, any attempts on bringing offsprings may result in severe birth defects which will almost always lead to deaths or severely disabled children. It was therefore named "Ailartsua" by European colonists after how the continent has caused ail and the nearby islanders' name to the continent, "Artsua". The colonists in the 1600s found that in order to prevent the mysterious "Ailartsua syndrome", all food must rely on growing crops that originated in other continents (which consistently yields low in Ailartsua) and imports from overseas. Such burden was overwhelming and the settlements were greatly limited in size and population. Later, the British empire('s love for land down under) found another use of Ailartsua: as a sentence for prisoners who committed heavy crime, and shipped loads of them to the land down under. It more or less stayed like that until mid-1800s.
In our timeline, the existance of chirality was not discovered until 1802, and was only possible after physicists had an idea what plane polarized light and chemists became familiar at analyzing molecular structures through crystallization. This means Ailartsua is off-limits for large scale human settlements at least until early-1800s, when scientists can finally analyze what went wrong in Ailartsua and make practical solutions and/or large scale food freight became viable.
Side note: Food tracking became a concept much earlier in this world as what better poison could it be than a poison that looks the same, tastes the same and smells the same as genuine fruit?

Isn't this a duplicate of Kirt's answer?
